# jQueryUI dialog VS twitter bootstrap overlay, putting one above the other

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

On my web page i use a jQueryUI modal Dialog to show a loading message when a link is clicked. But in some pages i also use Twitter Bootstrap's modal overlays.

The TB overlays appear over the loading Dialog. But i want to loading Dialog to be always on top of EVERY div. I tried to change the `z-index` of the Dialog overlay, but that doesn't help.

I made a simple jsfiddle example of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/x76UH/1/

In there you can click a link which shows a TB overlay and underneath that appears a *LOADING* dialog. But i want to have that dialog on top of the TB overlay.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to give `ui-dialog` higher `z-index`:

```
.ui-dialog {
   z-index: 1060;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x76UH/4/)

Comment: Had to add `!important` to the `z-index`, otherwise it wouldn't work for me. But it works now, thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that this works when putting it into the `open:` part in Jquery Dialog... `.dialog({ open: function (e, u) { $(".ui-dialog").css({ "z-index": 9999 }); } });`

Answer (score 2):

You have to update also `z-index` in bootstrap elements: http://jsfiddle.net/x76UH/3/

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 9 !important;
}

#myModal {
    z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

Its quick fix to work with fiddle, but you should edit it in your style file (`bootstrap-combined.min.js`)

Answer (score 1):

modify the z-index of the loading dialog to some thing like `z-index: 10000;`